# Trying to do script to search user input in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to learn Bash scripting, and doing some excercises.

Right now trying to create script that search names and fetch records from a file.
The file content is like that: `Name:Phone:Email`
Example: `John Doe:123456789:jd@gmail.com`
However I have created a function

```
names=$(awk '{print $1}' $HOME/name_list.txt)

name_list()
{
for i in $names; do
    if [ "$i" == "$name" ];then  #name is user input from scriptfile.
        echo $names | grep -o $i | wc -l | tr "\n" " ";echo "person found" 
    else
        echo "Couldn't find anyone with given name"
    fi
done
}
```

What I', troubled with, my `if` condition generates "person found" output for every 'i' in the file. Likewise the `else` condition generates output for every 'i' that not matches. I can understand why it's working like that but I couldn't find a way to do that otherwise. I want my script to scan all files and generates only 1 output for total matches and only 1 output for if there are no matches.

Comment: Please put a example of the file name_list.txt

Comment: You should use `awk` for the whole text processing. Even if `awk` isn't shell, that would the _shell way_ of doing it. Now, if you really want to use pure shell (for practice purposes), then read the file line by line with `while read -r name _; do ...; done < "$HOME/name_list.txt"`, but get rid of the `grep` `tr` `wc` calls inside the loop, if possible

Comment: @JuranirSantos file content is like that. Name:Phone:Email Example: John Doe:123456789:jd@gmail.com. There are 5 records lined up like this.

Comment: @Fravadona i've done like that. But It says not found for every unmatched name from the lines in the file like in my script. Actually it's working same with my **for** loop. But what I want is that even if it finds 1 match in a 10-line file, it only writes that match, but does not activate else condition for other unmatched ones. Else condition should only be activated if no line matches are found in the entire file.
`while read -r name _;do if [ "$name" == "James" ];then echo $name; else echo "Not found";fi;done < "$HOME/isim_listesi.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to show "not found" message once..... You can try something like this:

```
names=$(awk -F'[:]' '{print $1}' name_list.txt)
IFS=$'\n'
name=$1
found=0

name_list(){
for i in $names; do
    if [ "$i" == "$name" ];then  #name is user input from scriptfile.
      echo "person found at line $(grep -n $name name_list.txt | cut -d: -f1)"
      found=1
      break
    fi
done

if [ $found == 0 ]
then
    echo "Couldn't find anyone with given name"
fi
}
```

I only added *-F'[:]*' in AWS line + *IFS=$'\n'*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Awk anyway, it makes sense to implement all of your logic in Awk.

```
awk -v name="$1" -F : '$1 == name { ++found }
  END { if (found) printf "Found %i instances of %s\n", found, name
     else printf "Not found: %s\n", name }' "$HOME/name_list.txt"
```

Comment: I couldn't get how to use that in my script. Changed whole for loop with that awk script but always gave me output `Not found: `
Sorry for my ignorance, it's bit complicated for me. Simple brief about how script works would be great.

Comment: If you saved it in `./script` and made the file executable, run with `./script "John Doe"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `name_list.txt` is as-advertised (just a list of names), then you should be able read `grep`'s search strings from a file with...

```
echo $names | grep --file=$HOME/name_list.txt # ...
```

I should mention that `grep` also provides `-c` or `--count`, which counts the matches.  Using a modern style of `grep`, you'll also want to know about `-w` or `--word-regexp`, which will refuse to match target patterns if they don't represent a full word (or set of words) in the source, so that "John" won't match "Johnson."

That'll require reorganizing your script, since `grep` does most of the work, and might violate the terms of the exercise that you actually *want* to do, of course.  In that case, you might want to write the line-by-line results to a temporary file, then add them up for the output.